# Parse Cloud - Why need this?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm new to parse and i've just setup my server and dashboard on my local machine.

For my use, i just not need the simple API from parse, i need to write a server (with NodeJS + Express) to handle users request.

I've just see how to integrate an Express application with parse, so my application instead of the server directly will use my server that will serve:

1. The standard Parse API (/classes etc)
2. All my others route, that could not to depend on Parse API

This is correct ?

Reading online i've see that Parse Cloud need to extend Parse functionality with additional "routing" (if i have understand well).

So, in my application i will have

1. The standard API (ad described up here)
2. All other routers (that could not depend on Parse)
3. Other routers (that come from Cloud) and use Parse API

So, Parse Cloud is just a "simple" way to write additional Routing ? (i've see that exists the job function too, but right now i've not studied it).

My question is just because i'm a little confused about the real needed, just would like to have more info on "when to use it"

Thanks

**EDIT**

I provide here an example (that in part come from Parse Docs).

I have a `Video` class with an director name **field**.

In my Application (iOs, Android etc) i setup a view that need to know all the Video provided from a particular **director**.

I will have three ways:

1. Get all Videos (/classes/videos) and then filter it directly in APP
2. Write an NodeJS + Express router endpoint (http://blabla.com/videos/XXX) where XXX is the director and then get the result with Parse JS API and send back it to the app
3. Write an Clound function (that if i have understand respond to /functions/) that do the same as the router one.

This is just a little example, but is this the usage of Parse Cloud ? (or at least, one on them :))

Comment: If you dont create any cloud code functions it is fine and you dont have to worry about it at all, If you want to remove them from the Parse server completely you can do it too, but I think it will bring you a lot of troubles in the end...

Comment: I know that Parse.com will shut down, but i'm using the public relase version that can be installed locally and use it in production (just like parse.com), as Mazel said. However, i can embed parse in my Node+Express App and use Cloud Coude to write additional enpint (just like router) does. This is the benefit of it right ?

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand :-D, cloud code is mostly used for doing something with data when they are being saved, or before they are being send, also for sending push notifications and more...

Comment: read my update :) I've provided a little example where i try to explain my "doubts" :D

Comment: each video can have a pointer to the Director class and you can easily do queries based on that, if the video can be created by more than one Directors use Relation ( they are for many to many relationship between classes)

Comment: Yes, mine was just an example, sure i can structure well this relations, but my edit was just to understand the real use of this Cloud :)